# Calling Python trips an error from Objective-C

Tags: python, objective-c, xcode, osx-lion, bridge

I have been reading everything I could find on using the Python Objective c bridge. My main app is in Objective C. At this stage I just want to be able to call functions in Python.  I think there is something fundamental I'm doing wrong, but just can't see it. BTW, I'm running Lion, using XCode 4 and linking to Python.framework.

In the bundle I establish a file called PythonStuff.py, which looks like the following...

```
import objc
from Foundation import *
NSObject = objc.lookUpClass('NSObject')

class PythonStuff(NSObject):
    def init(self):
        self = super(PythonStuff, self).init()
        return self

    def pySetAString_(self, aString):
        #self._whatisit(aNumber)
        try:
            self.MyString = aString
        except:
            self.MyString = "blah" 
        return
```

I then set up the following protocol

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class PythonStuff;

@interface NSObject (PythonMethods)

-(void) pySetAString:(NSString *) value;

@end
```

Lastly, to call it I run the following code

```
if( ! Py_IsInitialized() )
        Py_Initialize();
PyThreadState *tstate = Py_NewInterpreter();
Class PythonStuffClass = NSClassFromString(@"PythonStuff");
id myPythonStuff;

myPythonStuff = [[PythonStuffClass alloc] init];
[myPythonStuff pySetAString:@"some silly string"];
```

From some of the samples I've seen I would've thought it would've worked, but I just can't see why it's not. I can set up simple Python classes without any functions and they appear to work, at least they don't trip an error, but the moment I try and call a function the call aborts, which to me looks like a library of some sort is missing either in Objective-C or as a Python import.

I've put in an exception handler for Objective-C.  Here's what it shows:-

0 objc_exception_throw
4 ffi_closure_SYSV
5 -[EditorViewItem runThread:]
6 [NSThread main]

Comment: Please include the backtrace of the crash. Which line exactly is the crash occurring on?

Comment: Further to the last comment, I've now provided in the source how I fire up the interpreter. In the meantime I also a Throw All Objective-C exceptions breakpoint. I've put into the question what happens.